# Turing Completeness in the real world

Tags: turing-machines, turing-complete

Real programs can solve problems given enough time and space. For every problem instance of known size, there is fixed upper bound on the amount of space which is consumed.

Are there problems that cannot be solved (i.e. functions which cannot be computed), given "just" a sufficiently large memory?

More concretely, are there functions which can only be computed by a Turing Machine (which has infinite tape), but not by a conventional program?

Comment: Q1 Yes. Q2 Without memory there is limit..

Comment: Sorry, your question is hard to understand. What do you mean by "For every problem instance of known size"? For instance, your problem is to "Find first 1000 prime numbers". What is its size?

Comment: By size, I was referring to the size of the input.If the problem you mentioned is formulated as: "Find the first n prime numbers?", then the size of the problem instance, is the necessary space to store the input: log (n), if you use a binary encoding.

Comment: @user3383312 Removed comment...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a Turing machine to actually consume an infinite amount of tape during any particular execution, because it must halt after a finite number of steps.  If it does not halt, then it has not "solved" anything.  Since the machine can only run for a finite number of steps, it can only move a finite distance from its starting point in either direction, and thereby consume only a finite amount of tape.

> More concretely, are there functions which can only be computed by a Turing Machine (which has infinite tape), but not by a conventional program?

Sure.  But only by virtue of requiring an unreasonable (finite) amount of time or space.

Comment: Indeed. However, is it possible that the machine consumes a finite amount of tape, whose value cannot be bound as a function of the input's size?

Comment: @user3383312: f(x) = "The amount of tape required to solve [some problem] of size x."  Did you perhaps mean a [polynomial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE) or [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPSPACE)?

Comment: I was thinking at the following fictitious situation: say there is a property P of natural numbers, and suppose we know that there are only k naturals which satisfy P. However, we have no idea which may be the largest such number. A Turing Machine building the set of P-numbers will stop when k numbers are generated, however it may consume arbitrarily large (yet finite) tape. Does that make sense?

Comment: We may not know the largest natural with P, but said natural still *exists*.

Comment: For an actual example of a function of the form "the amount of tape required for..." see the [busy beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver), which is of course non-computable.

Comment: Thanks! I think this captures precisely what I had in mind!